# rails access all has_many through records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models: Writer, Book, Page.

```
Writer has_many :books
Writer has_many :pages, through: :books
Book has_many :pages
```

I want to **display all the pages that belong to the writer through the book**, but it gives out an error:

```
Writer.first.books #=> works, shows all writer books
Book.first.pages #=> works, shows all book pages
Writer.first.books.pages #=> does not work, must in theory display all pages that belong to the writer
```

What are the best ways to show all the pages, except of using `each do |x|`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Writer.first.books` is a collection and will display all the books from the first `Writer`, that's why you see an error when calling `pages` on it; `pages` need to be called from a `Book` or `Writer` object (not a collection).

So, assuming that your associations are complete like, for example:

```
class Writer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  has_many :pages, through: :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :writer
  has_many   :pages
end

class Page < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :book
end
```

you should be able to get call `pages` directly on `Writer`, like this:

```
Writer.first.pages
```